# Solve the magnitudes of the solutions

Tags: polynomials

I was wondering how I could do these two problems

x^2 + 1=0

x^3 + 1 = 0

I m trying to find the roots and magnitudes of these questions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$$\mbox{x^2=-1}$$

$$\mbox{x = i and -i (These are complex roots)}$$
The Magnitude is $\sqrt{(-1)^2} = 1$

$$\mbox{x^3 = 1}$$

$$\mbox{x = 1}$$
The Magnitude is simply $1$

The general formula for finding the magnitude of a complex number:
$|a + bi| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$

Comment: I got that. How do I find the magnitude

Comment: This might help https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-the-magnitude-of-a-complex-number-for-example-5-5i